# How to reload app preferences and documents on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, preferences, plist

So I updated my iphone to new iOS and then my backup became corrupted.

I was then able to get ALL the information out of the backup unto my computer.

I now have for each app its corresponding `Library` and `Documents`.
These  contain additional folders that the apps use and the `Preferences` folder, which contains the `.plist` files.

I would like to put all this information back on my iPhone. But how?

Is there a program for this? Can this be done through iTunes?

I am quite desperate, as I would love to know how to get this done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you've installed the relevant apps back on the device, open [iExplorer](http://www.macroplant.com/iexplorer/) or similar app and copy the files back on to the device in the app's data container.

Comment: And how do I make the iPhone refresh its data after copying the relevant files back?

Comment: @HowToPutBackupBack Make sure the app isn't running in the background when you copy the files, then once you have, reboot the device.